# Getting a not defined error despite Vuex mapstate being defined in components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm having trouble getting vuex mapState functions to work. In my file TheHeaderComponent.vue, I'm trying to print both `{{ $store.state.coins }}` and `{{ coins }}` but only the former is being printed despite me passing in `...mapState['coins']` into the component.

The relevant error shown is `vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Property or method "coins" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Wondering if someone could shed some light on what I should be doing?

```
# TheHeaderComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ $store.state.coins }}</p>
    <p>{{ coins }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'TheHeader',
  computed: {
    ...mapState['coins'],
  },
  methods: {
  },
};
</script>
```

Interesting, if I replace `...mapState['coins']` with an actual computed function (see following code), `{{ coins }}` works.

```
coins() {
  return this.$store.state.coins;
},
```

I've also included the other files for reference (only relevant code).

```
# mutations.js
export const setStudentId = (state, value) => {
  state.studentId = value;
};


export const setCoins = (state, value) => {
  state.coins = value;
};


# store.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    coins: -1,
  },
  mutations,
});

# main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import App from './App.vue';

import {store} from './store/store';

// allows us to use the vue debugger
Vue.config.devtools = true;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  // we pull information about user
  mounted: function() {
    axios
        .get('/api/v1/core/token/')
        .then((response) => {
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token '
            + response.data.token;
          this.$store.commit('setStudentId', response.data['student_id']);
        })
        // pulls basic information on student
        .then((response) => {
          return axios
              .get('/api/v1/core/student/' + this.$store.state.studentId);
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.$store.commit('setCoins', response.data['coins']);
        });
  },
  render: (h) => h(App),
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
...mapState(['coins']),
```

You forget about `()`